# Why isn't my jQuery tooltip acting like a jQuery tooltip?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm working on presenting yet another periodic table, and am running into issues with jQuery UI tooltips. The page ends, without JavaScript errors, at:

```
<script src="/js/vendor/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2/ui/jquery.ui.tooltip.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).tooltip();
</script>
```

Earlier it was giving no JavaScript errors but a default styled (Chrome yellow on black, small font size) tooltip, unlike the tooltip in the jQuery UI demo at http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ (both for a td and a td > span). Now it displays the screen contents for a second or so, and then blanks out the display.

What is wrong with http://JonathansCorner.com/periodic/content.html and how can I fix it so it displays the page normally and displays jQuery UI's default tooltip version of a tooltip? The top left corner has a title.

Comment: Did you include the stylesheet(s)?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

Comment: I had a syntax error in including the stylesheet,but correcting that doesn't result in changed behavior. The screen goes blank the instant I mouse down from browser chrome into the HTML webpage.

Comment: You are putting the tooltip on document. Doesn't it require a html, head and body tag?

Comment: Thank you; it may; however, adding a DOCTYPE, html, head, and body elements has not altered the behavior that I can see.

Comment: I created this fiddle, with the markup of your page. Please note that the fiddle will actually add the html, head and body tag... and it seems to work fine: http://fiddle.jshell.net/BBa4t/

Comment: Hmm... The fiddle does exactly what I want but I don't see what is different besides different versions of jQuery / jQuery UI, and surrounding information that I have added. I tried adding the same libraries and versions I was using, and it displayed a working result.

Comment: @Yeronimo, I copied the fiddle and it worked. Please restate your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this fiddle, with the markup of your page. Please note that the fiddle will actually add the html, head and body tag... and it seems to work fine: fiddle.jshell.net/BBa4t

Answer (score 2):

Instead of your script:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).tooltip();
</script>
```

Try this script:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(document).tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

You are also not specifying a complete `HTML` document.  Where are your `HTML`, `HEAD`, `BODY`, etc. tags?  After adding these I would include the jQuery assets in the `HEAD` section instead of at the bottom of your page.

It looks like you are also including the tooltip javascript twice. In these lines:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2/ui/jquery.ui.tooltip.js"></script>
```

It looks like your `jquery-ui.js` already contains the tooltip widget so you don't need the second inclusion of `jquery.ui.tooltip.js`.